# SIGABRT error while saving/fetching core data

Tags: swift, core-data, increment

I am trying to save and fetch an integer in core data but am getting a SIGABRT error and I have no clue what is causing it, I think it might have to do with something in my incrementing function, anyone know what is wrong?

```
@IBAction func swipedUp(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        self.definitionLabel.isHidden = false
        do {
            scoreNumber = try context.fetch(Score.fetchRequest()) as? Score
            counter = Int(scoreNumber!.number)
            counter += 1
            scoreNumber?.number = Int16(counter)
            ad.saveContext()

        } catch {

        }
    }

func getScore() {

        do {
            fetched = try context.fetch(Score.fetchRequest()) as? Score
            counter = Int(fetched!.number)
            self.cardsStudiedLabel.text = "\(counter)"
        } catch {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you at least point out the exact line of code causing the error?

Comment: I am not sure which line it is but it is giving me this error: An NSManagedObject of class 'Score' must have a valid NSEntityDescription.'

Comment: The issue was in the auto-generated file, I have fixed it and everything is working properly. Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: You should either delete this question or post a full answer below if you think it will help others.

Comment: Does this code really work? `fetch` is supposed to return a non-optional(!) **array** of the entity (`[Score]` in this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to fix this issue all you have to do is delete @objc("entityName") in the generated .CoreDataClass.swift file